# Including controllers, services and directives

Tags: angularjs

Currently my index.html file is like this

```
<script src="controller-a></script>
<script src="controller-b></script>
<script src="controller-c></script>
```

and so on for all of my other controllers, services and directives.

Which seems very inconvenient if I have like 100 files, but one page only needs like one controller and service maybe.

What is the proper way to include a controller and a service to a page, route?
So that I don't have to load all the other 100 that I don't need.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look on some of the starter kits available, for example this https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter, or this for browserify https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate, they will demonstrate best practices

Comment: you can use gulp for adding all files to one file then load that one file in index file link https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gulp/grunt for this problem code will as below

```
 gulp.task('app-js', function () {
 return gulpMerge(
  gulp.src('static/src/tpl/*.html')
    .pipe(minifyHtml({empty: true}))
    .pipe(ngtemplate({
      module: 'genTemplates',
      standalone: true
    })
  ), gulp.src([
    'static/src/js/app.js',
    'static/src/js/locale_zh-cn.js',
    'static/src/js/router.js',
    'static/src/js/tools.js',
    'static/src/js/services.js',
    'static/src/js/filters.js',
    'static/src/js/directives.js',
    'static/src/js/controllers.js'
  ])
 )
 .pipe(concat('app.js'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/js/'));
 });
```

Hope this may help you. refer [Gulp merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge)